# Can't get Virtualbox to work with Genymotion

Tags: virtualbox

I started genymotion and got the following error-message:

> Unable to load VirtualBox engine.
>
> Make sure that it is properly installed before starting Genymotion.
>
> For more information, please refer to https://www.genymotion.com/#!/support?chapter=vbox#faq
>
> Genymotion log archive has been saved in: /home/seel93/genymotion-log.zip
> Please contact Genymotion support for more help.

I've looked over FAQ with no luck even though I've followed their walkthrough for Linux.

This command:

```
sudo /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh status
```

gives the following output:

> VirtualBox kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) are loaded.

Restarting Virtualbox did not do the trick either as mentioned in many similar posts. Any help would be much appriciated.

Answer (score 9):

I'm using xubuntu 16.04 LTS and i was having the same error i tried this and worked:

```
sudo /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup
```

it should say this:

> Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
>   Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
>   Starting VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.

and then you can check if that worked using:

```
sudo /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh status
```

then try to run again genymotion :) i hope that helps!

Comment: it worked! cheers!!! :)

Comment: did not work for me. I'm on Kubuntu 16.10, Genymotion 2.9.0 and Virtualbox 5.1.22. The status command indicated "VirtualBox kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) are loaded."

Comment: well, good thing I kept my Genymotion 2.8, but it's not ideal.

Comment: I've installed Virtualbox before genymotion still it gave me an error `Can't get Virtualbox to work with Genymotion`. By trying your solution it says no such file or directory.

Comment: I had downloaded from my distro app store and faced the same issue, then I overwritten the installation by installing from the terminal following the steps described at https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads and it fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

I get this when I've used up all 128 of my host-only NAT adapters,

I've searched the web and there doesn't seem to be way to a) remove them all in a batch or b) make Genymotion use the same one instead of creating a new one every time it starts. (Although one page I read made it sound like that is supposed to be the case!)

The fix for me:

1. Start VirtualBox
2. Go to File -> Preferences -> Network and open the "Host-only Networks" tab
3. One by one remove the vboxnet(0 to 127)'s!

Although you could just remove one and then start Genymotion - but you'd have to do it again next time! :)

Now if anyone knows how to stop Genymotion creating them ...

Answer (score 1):

I ended up simply installing virtualbox that is available in Ubuntu app store, and voila Genymotion worked :)

I previously tried to download the latest from their website, but that seemed to display this error.